# jquery UI select menu and knockout.js performance

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am trying to get the jquery ui selectmenu plugin to play nice with knockout.js, including adding options and having it update.  I have working code below but the performance isnt that great.  Is there a better alternative.  The reason I am doing a timeout is because the array sometimes isnt bound yet to the select and the selectmenu is empty.

https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dropdownlist = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var values = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

                if (allBindings.options) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(element).selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu(values || {});
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    $(element).selectmenu(values || {});
                }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the timeout if you put the 'dropdownlist' binding after the 'options' binding, e.g. `options: speeds, value: selectedSpeed, dropdownlist: {style: 'popup'}`. Also, you don't need to call the 'destroy' method each time the options change, according to the selectmenu link you posted.

As I've commented in another recent question of yours regarding performance, take a look at [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html).

Here's a fiddle using the selectmenu binding (which I modified), demonstrating 2 ways of manipulating the underlying observableArray, and their performance: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/PFddY/)